Cors issue arising only for endpoints which are exposed and managed by spring boot oauth2-authorization-server
I'm using spring boot 3 and built an oauth2 custom authorization server for security of my application, all the routes are protected by it. But the issue is the routes which I have created  when accessed by the sources which I have configured to all without cors issues are working fine and only throwing a unauthorized error when tried to access without access token , but the routes which are exposed and managed by authorization server for issuing tokens internally , those routes when I try to access from the same source throwing me cors issues. Can anyone help me solve this issue?
This my security configuration for my application
@Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain appSecurity(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        

        httpSecurity.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(request-> request.anyRequest().authenticated())
                    .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                     .cors(c -> c.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                   
                    .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }



@Bean
    public org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:5173"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        
        org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("http://localhost:8085/oauth2/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

giving me cors issues when i try to access /oauth2/token or /oauth2/authorize etc routes which are managed by oauth2
